# How do I check if a type is a subtype OR the type of an object?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, subclass

To check if a type is a subclass of another type in C#, it's easy:

```
typeof (SubClass).IsSubclassOf(typeof (BaseClass)); // returns true
```

However, this will fail:

```
typeof (BaseClass).IsSubclassOf(typeof (BaseClass)); // returns false
```

Is there any way to check whether a type is either a subclass OR of the base class itself, without using an `OR` operator or using an extension method?

Answer (score 622, accepted):

Apparently, no.

Here's the options:

- Use [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `is` and `as`

### Type.IsSubclassOf

As you've already found out, this will not work if the two types are the same, here's a sample [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    typeof(Derived).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)).Dump();
    typeof(Base).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)).Dump();
}

public class Base { }
public class Derived : Base { }
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Which indicates that `Derived` is a subclass of `Base`, but that `Base`is (obviously) not a subclass of itself.

### Type.IsAssignableFrom

Now, this will answer your particular question, but it will also give you false positives. As Eric Lippert has pointed out in the comments, while the method will indeed return `True` for the two above questions, it will also return `True` for these, which you probably don't want:

```
void Main()
{
    typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Derived)).Dump();
    typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Base)).Dump();
    typeof(int[]).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(uint[])).Dump();
}

public class Base { }
public class Derived : Base { }
```

Here you get the following output:

```
True
True
True
```

The last `True` there would indicate, if the method *only* answered the question asked, that `uint[]` inherits from `int[]` or that they're the same type, which clearly is not the case.

So `IsAssignableFrom` is not entirely correct either.

### `is` and `as`

The "problem" with `is` and `as` in the context of your question is that they will require you to operate on the objects and write one of the types directly in code, and not work with `Type` objects.

In other words, this won't compile:

```
SubClass is BaseClass
^--+---^
   |
   +-- need object reference here
```

nor will this:

```
typeof(SubClass) is typeof(BaseClass)
                    ^-------+-------^
                            |
                            +-- need type name here, not Type object
```

nor will this:

```
typeof(SubClass) is BaseClass
^------+-------^
       |
       +-- this returns a Type object, And "System.Type" does not
           inherit from BaseClass
```

### Conclusion

While the above methods might fit your needs, the only correct answer to your question (as I see it) is that you will need an extra check:

```
typeof(Derived).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)) || typeof(Derived) == typeof(Base);
```

which of course makes more sense in a method:

```
public bool IsSameOrSubclass(Type potentialBase, Type potentialDescendant)
{
    return potentialDescendant.IsSubclassOf(potentialBase)
           || potentialDescendant == potentialBase;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as the correct answer (gotta wait 8 more minutes) since you mentioned that the check has to be reversed and provided a link to the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually do what the question asked for; this does not determine whether one type is a subclass of another, but rather whether one type is assignment compatible with another. An array of uint isn't a subclass of an array of int, but they are assignment compatible. IEnumerable<Giraffe> isn't a subclass of IEnumerable<Animal>, but they are assignment compatible in v4.

Comment: How would `IsInstanceOfType` fit into this?

Comment: why does `typeof(List<object>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(IList<object>))` return false?

Comment: @NileshBarai Because a class is not a *subclass* of an interface it *implements*. Use `typeof(Test).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ITest))` to test if a class implements an interface, or `typeof(ITest).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Test))`

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer: any objections if you could clarify the following statement: `"The last True there would indicate, if the method only answered the question asked, that uint[] inherits from int[] or that they're the same type, which clearly is not the case."` ----> it is not clear to me what's going on here - why should it not return true? (I'm confused).

Comment: Because `IsAssignableFrom` answers a different question than "if a type is a subtype of another type" type of question. It tries to answer if `a = b` will work. Been a while since I looked at these things, and I don't know why IsAssignableFrom returns `true` here, since you can't actually directly assign a `uint[]` array to a `int[]` variable, or vice versa, but I guess some coercion can be done somewhere. In any case, `int[]` is *not* a subtype of `uint[]`, or the other way around, so using `IsAssignableFrom` to answer that question is not correct. Might be close enough for your needs though.

Comment: Why not `IsAssignableTo`? Isn't `typeof(Derived).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Base))` doing the same thing?

Comment: @Ahmad `IsAssignableTo` is just method that reverses the positions of the two types involved, it calls `IsAssignableFrom` under the hood, and thus have the same issue as described in the answer above. Granted, the issue might not be relevant for your particular code, but it's the same thing at least.

Answer (score 43):

```
typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(unknownType);
```

Answer (score 12):

You should try using [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do it in a Xamarin Forms PCL project, the above solutions using `IsAssignableFrom` gives an error:

> Error: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsAssignableFrom' and
>   no extension method 'IsAssignableFrom' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

because `IsAssignableFrom` asks for a `TypeInfo` object.
You can use the `GetTypeInfo()` method from `System.Reflection`:

`typeof(BaseClass).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(unknownType).GetTypeInfo())`

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer with the hope of someone sharing with me if and why it would be a bad idea.  In my application, I have a property of Type that I want to check to be sure it is typeof(A) or typeof(B), where B is any class derived from A.  So my code:

```
public class A
{
}

public class B : A
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Type _helperType;
    public Type HelperType
    {
        get { return _helperType; }
        set 
        {
            var testInstance = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(value);
            if (testInstance==null)
                throw new InvalidCastException("HelperType must be derived from A");
            _helperType = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I might be a bit naive here so any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with that idea: 1) the type needs a parameterless constructor or CreateInstance will fail; 2) casting to (A) doesn't return null if the cast can't be made, it throws; 3) you don't actually need the new instance, so you have a useless allocation. The accepted answer is better (though not perfect).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Very helpful.