# Define a class MyClass<T> or a function MyFunction<T>(T x) where T can only by a type that implements IMyInterface

Tags: c#, metaprogramming

I want to define a class `MyClass<T>` and a very particular function `MyFunc<T>`, but I want to force `T` to inherit from (in any way) an interface or a class. Let's call this `IMyInterface`.

The only way my knowledge of C# allows me to do this is to define a generic class, check if it inherits (see [How do I check if a type is a subtype OR the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/in-c-how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object) for example), and throw an exception otherwise.

Is there a way to force this at compile-time, rather than runtime?

Comment: If you already limit the use to one Interface, are you sure generics is the way to go? Instead of for example `MyFunc<T>(T obj) where T : IMyInterface { ... }` wouldn't a simple `MyFunc(IMyInterface obj) { ... }` be enough?

Comment: @Corak I actually want to store and return values of the same type, avoid casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic type constraints:

```
public void MyFunc<T>() where T : IMyInterface {
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to ensure the class has a copy constructor in addition to this?

Comment: No. You can only enforce a default constructor with no parameters. What you _could_ do is enforce an interface with a `Copy` method.

Comment: No use in my case. I'm mainly using `double`s and they don't have `Copy`. Thanks, though.

I wanted to do this just so I could avoid assigning a reference, which isn't what what I want.