# Check the actual type of an object

Tags: c#

I have:

`class A`
`class B : A`
`class C : B`
`class D : B`

And I have a List

Where actual objects of C and D are stored.

How can I check whether the objects in List is a subtype of B?

Currently, I'm doing `item.GetType() == typeof(C) || item.GetType() == typeof(D)`

This works, but what if I had more than 2 classes that are inherited from B? Writing all of them down seems redundant. Is there a way to check whether the object is a subtype of B? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/in-c-how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `is` keyword.

```
if(item is B)
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using casts?
Check [this](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/25168/cast-c-sharp) out if you dont know what it is

> In case of cast operations that involve base and derived types, there
> is a risk of throwing exceptions. To test for compatibility before
> actually performing a cast, C# has provided two operators to allow
> casting safely without causing any exceptions. The two operators are:
>
> **The ‘Is’ operator** used to check for successful casting from one reference type to another and to determine an object ‘s type without
> casting it.
> **The ‘As’ operator** used to obtain the cast value, if the cast can be made successfully and hence more efficient.