# How do I use reflection to see if a field in a class is another class

Tags: c#, object, reflection, field

I have a very simple object like:

```
public class ChargeTemplate
{
    public string ChargeTemplateType;
    public string TemplateCode;
    public string ChargeDescription;
    public string Active;

    public Calculation ChargeTemplateCalculation;
    public TApplication ChargeTemplateApplication;
    public Taxation ChargeTemplateTaxation;
}
```

I'm filling out some of the fields and then passing it to this method:

```
public void FillChargeTemplateFields(object items)
{

 foreach (var prop in items.GetType().GetFields())
 {
   ...
 }

}
```

Inside I'm grabbing the name and the value.

When I get down to Calculation, I want to know that it's a new class with fields so that I can throw it back up into the method to get it's field names and values.  But I can't seem to figure out how to determine that it's a class as well.  How do I do this?

Comment: Check this out, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/in-c-how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object

Comment: Yes, I have.  I've spent the last hour going over questions that are close but did not provide the answer I needed.

Comment: What qualifies as a type you want to call your method again with?

Comment: Just another class with fields in it.

Comment: That's not going to be nearly specific enough-- there are many types in `System` that meet that criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for namespace name in FieldType allowed me to determine it was one of my classes, at which point I just passed back the value.