# How can I tell if one object is derived from a particular class

Tags: c#, subclass, typeof

I was asked for more info: The original problem is below

I saw the answer I was pointed to above.  I did look before posting.  That is how I found `.IsSubclassOf` which I didn't know existed (I am VERY new to `C#`).

What I don't understand is why I am getting an error when I try to use the command.

I need to be able to tell if some object O is a sub-class of some other class C.  It is okay if I specify the type of class C is directly (such as `ListBox`) but what class `O` is will vary, which is why I need to check.  O might be one of many objects derived from `ListBox` or it might be an object derived from `TextBox` or it might be something else.  I need to be able to act on those cases where a method is being passed objects that are derived from or sub-classes of ListBox or whatever class O may or may not be derived/sub-classed from

The example I give below would work fine ***if*** "st" could work in last statement.  But it doesn't work.  It gives me an error.  I am told that I can not use a variable there--I have to use a Type.  But the variable IS a type.  I declare it as a type above.  I can't name the type specifically because I will not know the type of the object.  I have to get it with `GetType`.

---

Original problem/post:

I need to be able to tell if an instance of an object is derived from a particular class.

This is just some example code to test the `type of` and `"is a IsSubclassOf"` methods, but they do not seem to work for me.

```
ListBox tb = new ListBox();
NoVerticalScrollCheckedListBox nvlb = new NoVerticalScrollCheckedListBox();
Type st = nvlb.GetType();
Type uType = tb.GetType();
bool b = typeof(st).IsSubclassOf(uType);
Console.Write("BOOL: " + b);
```

I get the error that I am trying to use variable st as a type, but st is a type.  I can put in the actual class name such as `"NoVerticalScrollCheckedListBox"` but that will not give me the information I want because what I want to be able to discover is if a particular object instance is derived from another class, not whether or not the class is derived from that other class abstractly.

I would like to make a method, for example, that would treat all objects derived from a ListBox in a particular way, regardless of whether it is one of several existing sub-types or of a new sub-type that may come along.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - particularly the "not whether or not the class is derived from that other class abstractly". What are you *actually* trying to determine? What information do you have at compile-time? What do you expect `typeof(st)` to do, given that `st` is already a reference to a `Type` object? I'm sure that what you want to do is feasible - we just need to understand it properly. (In particular, why do you want to treat different subclasses of ListBox differently anyway?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, how do I check if a type is a subtype OR the type of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/in-c-how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object)

Comment: This: `typeof(st)` is not correct, `st` is already a type, you can just use: `st.IsSubClassOf(uType)`.

Answer (score 8):

Using reflection for common tasks is a good indicator that there’s a better way. A promising first step seems like it could be:

```
bool b = nvlb is ListBox;
```

Depending on how you’re using this information, though, even this might not be necessary. You should describe the purpose of your method in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass an instance of the type you are comparing.

```
public class Base{}    
public class Child : Base{}
public class ChildOfChild : Child{}
public class Another{}

//...

bool b1 = typeof(Child).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)); //true
bool b2 = typeof(ChildOfChild).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)); //true
bool b3 = typeof(Another).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base)); //false
```

If you want to check the current instance you can use **as** instead of **is**.

```
Child c = new Child();
//...

Base b = c as Base;
if(b != null)
{
    //...
}
```