# Calling item methods on an array of different types

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, dynamic

My task is simple: I have to create a dynamic array (which means that its size can change during all runtime) and fill it (depends on user input, also in runtime) with objects of different types. Moreover, it should be possible for me to access fields (and/or methods) of every object in the array. Obviously, fields are different for each type. Simplified structure:

```
public class Point {}
public class RightTriangle:Point { public double sideA, sideB; }
public class Circle:Point { public double radius; }
public class Cone:Circle { public double radius, height; }
```

So, you see: all classes inherit one base class. And I know, these structure kind of illogical, but that's not my choice. So, I want this code to work:

```
RightTriangle rt1 = new RightTriangle();
Cone cn1 = new Cone();
List<Point> objs = new List<Point>();
objs.Add(rt1);
sideA_tb.Text = objs[0].sideA.ToString();
```

But it doesn't. Compiler says that there is no `sideA` in `Point`. However this does not work either:

```
public class Point { public double sideA, sideB, radius, height; }
public class RightTriangle:Point { public new double sideA, sideB; }
public class Circle:Point { public new double radius; }
public class Cone:Circle { public new double radius, height; }
```

It seems that values from actual class (`rt1`, which is `RightTriangle`) do not override ones in `Point` class, so I've got something like this:

```
List<Point> objs = new List<Point>();
objs.Add(rt1); // rt1 has fields 'sideA' = 4, 'sideB' = 5
sideA_tb.Text = rt1.sideA.ToString(); // Got 4, okay
sideA_tb.Text = objs[0].sideA.ToString(); // Got 0, what the?
```

So, basically, I need a dynamic array of links, and I want to use this links to access objects fields and methods. Also, I know that I can write some `Get/Set` functions in base class and override them in child classes, but this does not seems like beauty solution.
Thanks in advance and please forget my illiteracy (English isn't my native).

Comment: `sideA_tb.Text = ((RightTriangle)objs[0]).sideA.ToString();`

You need to cast it back from a `Point` to the correct class type

Comment: [Read up here for checking the base type of your `Point` class, to make sure you don't accidently cast to the wrong type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object)

Comment: That works, thank you! But it means that I have to write some logic to define what type should I cast to for one or another object in the array, right? So can you please guide me to the best (I mean, not very ugly) way to do this? Maybe there are some already made methods?

Comment: What is Circle.sideA supposed to do? You should clean up the code, and extract type-specific behavior to separate methods. This would allow you to use method overloading and avoid type checking

Comment: @Urffly, thanks for accepting my answer. I recommend you read the updated version I just posted because I go a little bit into design quesions you should consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it (in theory):

```
public class Point { public virtual double sideA, sideB, radius, height; }
public class RightTriangle:Point { public override double sideA, sideB; }
```

To make properties and methods overridable in derived classes they have to be declared `virtual` in the base class. The overriding class has to declare the overriden property/method as `override`.

In practice you cannot make fields `virtual`, only properties and methods can be. So you have to change your code as follows:

```
public class Point { 
    public virtual double sideA { get; set; } 
    public virtual double sideB { get; set; }
    public virtual double radius { get; set; }
    public virtual double height { get; set; }
}

public class RightTriangle:Point { 
    public override double sideA { get; set; }
    public override double sideB { get; set; }
}
```

However, you should not do this as it is very bad design. More below.

#### So what's the difference to `new`?

When a method is *overriden* it will be decided *at runtime* whether the overridden or the original implementation will be called.

So when a method receives a `Point` as argument, that `Point` instance might actually be a `RightTriangle` or a `Circle`.

```
Point p1 = new RightTriangle();
Point p2 = new Circle();
```

In the above example, both `p1` and `p2` are `Point`s from the perspective of the code that uses `p1` and `p2`. However, "underneath" they are actually instances of the derived classes.

So with my solution, when you acess `p1.sideA` for example, the the *runtime* will look "underneath" and check what the `Point` really is: Is it actually a `RightTriangle`? Then check if there is an *overridden* implmentation of `sideA` and call that one. Is it actually a `Circle`? Then do the same check (which will fail) and call the *original* implmentation of `sideA`.

The `new` qualifier however does something else. It will not override a method, but create a completely *new* one (with the same name), that is handled differently *at compile time*.

So with your solution, the *compiler* sees that you created a `RightTriangle` and stored it in a variable of type `Point`. When you now access `p1.sideA` for example, the compiler will compile this access in such a way that it reads `sideA` from the *base* class, since the instance variable your are dealing with has the *base type*.

If you still want to access the `new` implementation, then your code using `p1` has to cast it to the correct derived type `RightTriangle`:

```
var w = ((RightTriangle)p1).sideA; // Gets correct value.
```

#### So what's the problem?

As you may have already noticed now, using `new` is not a good solution. The code that uses all kinds of `Point`s has to know whether a specific derivate of `Point` implements a field with `new` or not. Moreover it has to know, when it receives a `Point` instance what kind of instance it acutally is underneath. This will lead to lots of very elaborate `if`-`else` statements that check what *kind* of point `p1` is being dealt with and run the appropriate behvaiour.

Using `virtual` and `override` alleviates the last problem, but only if the base class implements *all* methods and properties any derived class implements. Which is basically kind of insane. You tried that and I'm sure you noticed on the way that it doesn't make much sense to give a `Point` a `sideA` and `sideB` *and* a `radius`. How could `Point` ever implement those properties meaningfully? And you cannot make them `abstract` either, because then a `Circle` also had to implement a `sideA` and so on.

#### So how to solve it in a better way?

Think about what you want to do whith this differnet point instances. You collect them together in a list for a reason: they have something in common. Also you iterate over this list doing something with each one of them for a specific reason as well. But what is it you are trying to do exactly? Can you describe it in an abstract way?

Maybe you are getting side lengths and radiuses to calculate the area? Then give `Point` a `virtual` method `GetArea()` and override it in each derived class. A method `GetArea()` makes sense on all derived types, although it is implemented differently in each one of them.

You could also make `GetArea()` an `abstract` method instead of a `virtual` one. This means it is not implemented in the base class at all and all derived types are *forced* to implement it on their own.

Maybe you don't want to handle all `Point`s in the list but the `RightTriangle`s only? Then the code doing this should only receive the `RightTriangle`s:

```
public void HandleRightTriangles(IEnumerable<RightTriangle> rts)
{
    // Can work with sideA and sideB directly here, because we know we only got triangles.
}
```

Call it with:

```
// using System.Linq;
HandleRightTriangles(objs.OfType<RightTriangle>());
```

Comment: Doing this method would be incorrect as not all classes use the properties. It's bad design at the moment, despite it fixing the issue, it fixes the issue in a bad way

Comment: Worth adding an explanation on how "new" works. The "new" keyword hides the base implementation if the object is accessed while cast to the new type, if you cast it back to the base type the "new" method won't be hidding the base implementation

Comment: I've already tries this, but I've got `CS0106 Compiler Error`, what basically says that I'm not able to use `override` nor `virtual` with fields.

Comment: @Urffly you can't and shouldn't be using fields as properties anyway. Fields are meant for *internal* data. They aren't part of the class's contract. You should define properties instead of fields

Answer (score 3):

```
RightTriangle rt1 = new RightTriangle();
Cone cn1 = new Cone();
List<Shape> objs = new List<Shape>();
objs.Add(rt1);
sideA_tb.Text = objs[0].sideA.ToString();
```

This doesn't compile as you are trying to get a `sideA` property from the class `Shape`, which doesn't exist. Since not all classes have a `sideA`, I wouldn't add that property to the `Shape` class either, since not all classes use the property of `sideA`, it would be bad OO design to put properties inside classes that wouldn't need them. Instead you need to check the type of class and cast it back:

```
RightTriangle rt1 = new RightTriangle();
Cone cn1 = new Cone();
List<Shape> objs = new List<Shape>();
objs.Add(rt1);
Shape object = objs[0];
RightTriangle rt = objs[0] as RightTriangle;
if (rt != null)
    sideA_tb.Text = rt.sideA.ToString();
```

To see more about checking the type of an object remember to refer to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)

**EDIT**

So your full class structure could be:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract double getArea();

    public override string ToString() {
        return "Area: " + this.getArea();
    }
}
public class RightTriangle:Shape {

    public double sideA {get; set;}
    public double sideB {get; set;}

    public override double getArea() {
        return (this.sideA * this.sideB)/2;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "Side A: " + this.sideA +" Side B: " + sideB + " " + base.ToString();
    }


}
public class Circle:Shape {

    public double radius {get; set;}

    public override double getArea() {
        return Math.Pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "Radius: " + this.radius  + " " + base.ToString();
    }
}
public class Cone:Circle {

    public double height {get; set;}

    public override double getArea() {
        //πr(r+sqrt(h^2+r^2))
        return Math.PI * this.radius * (this.radius + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(this.height, 2) + Math.Pow(this.radius, 2)));

    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return "Height : "+ height + " " + base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Cone will inherit radius from the Circle.

Then you need some checks to see what to do with them, a method like this could be a possibility:

```
public void doSomething(Shape obj) {
    RightTriangle rt = obj as RightTriangle;
    if (rt != null) {
        //Do something
    }
    Circle circle = obj as Circle;
    if (circle != null) {
        //Do something
    }
    Cone cone = obj as Cone;
    if (cone != null){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

[Here's a dotnetfiddle of it working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XgrcUg)

Do remember though, using `as` keyword, a `Cone` can be considered a `Circle`, but a `Circle` object cannot be considered a `Cone`

Comment: A far better option would be to clean up the code, extract type-specific methods and take advantage of overloading.

Comment: True @PanagiotisKanavos , but at their current class structure, there are no methods that could be overloaded from `Point` to the other classes. `Circle` doesn't have a `sideA` and `RightTriangle` doesn't have a `Radius`

Comment: a bad design should be fixed, not covered up. The Point/Circle etc hierarchy is a typical example on how to handle inheritance. BTW `as` would make even type checking a *lot* simpler

Answer (score 0):

There is no point on redifining the methods on the derived classes. This should work fine for you:

```
public class Point { public double x, y}
public class RightTriangle:Point { }
public class Circle:Point { public double radius; }
public class Cone:Circle { public height; }
```

NOTE: renamed "side" to axis names.

Comment: That's not a good design. Points and circles don't have sides.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. I hasn't really looking at the "domain" but to the oo concepts in place. I have renamed side to x and y but again I think the point of the question is about OO not geometry :)

Comment: What would the `x` and `y` be on a circle? Shouldn't it just have an `x` and then the `RightTriangle` and the `Cone` have a `y`? Circles only need radius generally for a measurement

Comment: @Draken again I am answering the OO part of the question, not the geometry. And I guess x and y in a circle will be the center point of it.

Answer (score -2):

The collection that you have is a a `List` of `Point`s.

When you add a `RightTriangle` or a `Circle` or a `Cone` these are being added as their base class a `Point`.
So when you index into your collection you are getting back an object of type `Point`, which as you well know has no fields.

After you've gotten your object out of the collection you'll have to cast back from a `Point` to it's concrete class such as:

```
var rightTriangle = new RightTriangle
{
    sideA = 10d,
    sideB = 15d
};

var points = new List<Point>
{
    rightTriangle
};

var indexedRightTriangle = (RightTriangle)points[0];
sideA_tb.Text = indexedRightTriangle.sideA;
```

I'd also look into the [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/scekt9xw.aspx) keyword which will come in handy when checking which type the object is when getting it back from the collection.
This can be used like:

```
var indexedPoint = points[0];
if(indexedPoint is RightTriangle)
{
    var indexedRightTriangle = (RightTriangle)indexedPoint;
    sideA_tb.Text = indexedRightTriangle.sideA;
}
```

You weren't too far away. But I'd recommend sticking with your first implementation as the second has `Point` implement all the different fields which are unnecessary for it's type.

Comment: When you retrieve a `Circle` item from the array, you get a `Circle` item, not a `Point` item. The fields are there. This is *not* a runtime error though. Without any other info, the compiler can't know whether the Point `variable` points to a Cirle, Point or whatever. Hence the compilation error. Casting to `RightTriangle` is *worse*, as it hides the compilation error and crashes at runtime. Using `is` or better yet, `as` isn't something to look into in this case, it's a necessity.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes the fields are there, but there is no compilation error as everything inherits from `Point`. Yes casting would throw an exception if the type was not checked. As in why I said that the OP should look into the `is` keyword.