# How to check which subclass is object of superclass?

Tags: c#

**To explain my question:**
Car, Boat, Airplane are subclasses from Toy class.
How can I check which subclass is object of Toy class?

Comment: Add some code. Now it is impossible to say something. What did you do until now?

Answer (score 0):

If your code goes like this:

```
public class Car : Toy
{
    //...    
}
```

Then the first thing that comes to my mind: [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

Example:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
if (myCar is Toy)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: That check can never fail, so I'm not sure what you are demonstrating?

Comment: It's just an example of using "is". Might've made it a bit more complicated, that's true

Comment: I have found similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2742288/1773972    you can use `Type.IsSubclassOf` too