# How to force the Type to be from a specific inheritance hierarchy in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary in my code like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Type, TypeHandler>();
```

I want to fill this dictionary with a list of Commands and their command handler classes. and All of the commands are inherited from the same class.

How can I force this inheritance hierarchy in the dictionary variable definitions?

Comment: You could abstract the dictionary to a class, and have the add method accept a generic type argument for the constraints that you need.

Comment: Where do you add entries to the dictionary? Can you check the key there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a type is a subtype OR the type of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object)

Comment: You need to state if any Key-Value restriction is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a class which is inherited from Dictionary<TKey, TValue> and make a constraint for it.

this is a sample code :

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> { }  

public sealed class CommandHandlerDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue: ICommandHandler<TKey> { }

public sealed class SampleCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<int> { }
```

usage :

```
var dic = new CommandHandlerDictionary<int, SampleCommandHandler>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do nothing. 'Type' should be the base class for 'Command(s?)'. It automatically restricts the key values:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class br {
    class ABase { public int I; }
    class B : ABase { public int J; }
    class C : ABase { public int K; }
    static void Main() {
        var a = new B();
        var hdr = new Dictionary<ABase, string>() {
            { a, "City" }, { new C(), "Date"} };
        Console.WriteLine(hdr[a]); // --> City
    }
}
```

The same for 'TypeHandler'.